# Function returning crazy values unless a temp value is declared and returned?

Tags: c++

I've been reading through Bjarne's book on Programming Principles and have been given a try this task to complete. The task wants the user to create a program that squares every number specifically without using the `*` operator. Sounds easy huh? However whilst adding the following code:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int square(int value, int ratio);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        cout << i << " Squared = " << i << " * " << i << " (" << square(i, i) << ")\n";
    }
}

int square(int value, int ratio)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < ratio; ++i)
    {
        value += value;
    }

    return value;
}
```

The values returned are drastically altered (until they leave the range of `int` variable and return 0). This is only changed when I add a `temp_value` and return said `temp_value` as shown:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int square(int value, int ratio);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        cout << i << " Squared = " << i << " * " << i << " (" << square(i, i) << ")\n";
    }
}

int square(int value, int ratio)
{
    int temp_value = value;

    for (int i = 1; i < ratio; ++i)
    {
        temp_value += value;
    }

    return temp_value;
}
```

It's probably something very simple but I can't seem to work out why this would be needed unless there is some form of object manipulation that occurs when it's parsed into the function.

Comment: By using a debugger or printing the value on each iteration, you would have find the answer yourself in less than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `square(4, 4)` your first code does:

```
 4 +  4 =  8
 8 +  8 = 16
16 + 16 = 32
```

your second:

```
 4 + 4 =  8
 8 + 4 = 12
12 + 4 = 16
```

I let you figure out why by yourself to not spoil you all the fun

Comment: Ahh I see now, just you saying that made me realise that by using the += operator, I was adding it to itself rather than incrementing the `value` object by the original `value` variable. I really should have thought about that by going through the computer minded process and step by step gone through each statement and function call.